# Wordpress too many redirects issue on localhost

Tags: wordpress

I am facing the issue as described in the title. I am working on a Woocommerce site with default WP Twenty Nineteen. Everything was working fine but I have mistyped https in the WP admin General Settings Site Url field. This caused too_many_redirects error on both Chrome and Mozilla. I have tried clearing cookies and complete browsing data, disabling plugins, changing permalinks and deleting htaccess file but none of this worked. Maybe this can help but strangely I can access admin but cannot see none of the pages. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to update your database and update the `site_url` and `home_url` fields in the wp_options table.

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config.php add this 2 lines (with your protocol+domain_name):

```
define('WP_HOME','https://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://yourdomain.com');
```